# How can I convert that QueryOver<> code to use Query<> with NHibernate 3.3

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a Class A that have a class B List ... 
So, with QueryOver I have :

```
ClassB lb = null;  
var result = session.QueryOver<ClassA>
        .JoinAlias(x => x.ListB, () => lb, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
        .Where(() => lb.Property == 1)
        .List<ClassA>();
```

How Can I do that using Nhibernate Query<> ?

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you want to do is get a list of `ClassA` having at least one `ClassB` with `Property == 1`:

```
var result = session.Query<ClassA>()
                    .Where(a => a.ListB.Any(b => b.Property == 1))
                    .ToList();
```

This wouldn't be an outer join, though. You might emulate that by adding `|| !a.ListB.Any()`.

Comment: The generated SQL is weird and I got an cast error on c# (But the sql worked on SQL Manager) ... If its the only way, I think QueryOver is the best option, right?

Comment: I don't have your source, so I can't know what your cast error is. About the sql being weird... uh? It's not like you have to maintain it manually. Last, QueryOver can be better or not, I still don't have enough information about what you need.

Comment: My example here is very simple... But I can have a complex scenario  like that : Object A -> List B -> Object C -> List D -> Object E -> Property E ... So I have to create a query to return Class A based in Property E ...

Comment: @Paul, I don't see any reference to C or D in your original query.